# scanning cd-rom fails to finish installation process for ubtuntu 16.04 LTS on Dell laptop

Tags: ubuntu, installation

i am trying to install ubtuntu 16.04 LTS, latest release as of writing, on a normal dell computer. it has a cd rom. I run through the normal GUI install process after i have booted into a trail version of ubtuntu from usb. i get to the 'scanning the CD-ROM...' part and the error pops up on the machine:

```
apt configuration problem
an attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed.
OK
```

when i click OK to remove the error message, it voids out the Install GUI and shows an alert on screen:

> Installation Complete Installation has finished. You can continue
>   testing Ubuntu now, but until you restart the computer, any changes
>   you make or documents you save will not be preserved.
>
> RESTART NOW

when i restart, ubuntu is not installed. it's as if half way through the install process, it tries to get info from a cd of all things, and then stops trying to install it.

this is super weird. i am looking for help and i appreciate any time you put into figuring this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a fix in [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/658865). Hope this helps you to recover the issue.

Please note that removing /usr/lib/ubiquity/apt-setup/generators/40cdrom from your system may cause the installer to crash at a later stage.

Original report follows:

Binary package hint: ubiquity

Description of problem:
When trying to install Ubuntu from USB, ubiquity crashes with this message: "An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed."

Root of problem:
The problem is that the file structure on the usb differs to what is on a livecd and apt-setup is unaware of this.

WORKAROUND:

There appear to be two alternatives:

a) Remove the script that causes the error, when installing from a Live setup ("Try Ubuntu"):

sudo rm /usr/lib/ubiquity/apt-setup/generators/40cdrom

b) Create the files as they are expected:

To resolve this, simply copy the contents of filesystem.squashfs on the iso into the usb stick. Luckily the parts it is reading from this appear to be just apt config files so the fact that you lose symbolic links or permissions on a FAT32 usb stick shouldn't matter.

On your current Linux installation: (If you don't have one you could use a live cd off a different usb stick)

1. Create USB stick.
2. Type in a terminal:

   sudo mkdir iso

   sudo mkdir source

   sudo mount -o loop pathtoiso/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso iso

   sudo mount -t squashfs -o loop iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs source

   sudo cp -pLr source/* pathtomountedusbstick.

Comment: This worked for you?